# The function which is calculating grandtotal price?

Tags: php, magento

I am currently using Magento 1.9 and I am looking for the file containing the PHP function in charge of calculating the grand total price of the order.

What I want to do is to remove the shipping tax from it.

If you know any other better method that I can show the shipping price next to the subtotal but not include it in the calculation of grand total final fee?

Comment: Have you checked Conguration->tax->Shopping cart display settings section. I think you can get solution from there instead of jumping in code.

Comment: Yes but it's not removing the shipping tax from the grand total fee..

Comment: Display Full Tax Summary?

Comment: Display Shipping Amount?

Comment: No it's not heling, it still shows the shipping price which i want but i don't want to calculate it in the grand total..

Comment: @user2942786 it's not as easy as "finding the file containing the function" as it's aggregated by an arbitrary number of "total collectors" which can modify that total. For your sake, you could add your own total collector to remove the shipping tax. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767483/custom-totals-collector-reorder-totals-in-totals-overview-in-checkout)